# Conditional Constraint Linear Program in Python's Pulp Module

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming, pulp

Is there a way to add a constraint within pulp in python that would count all the variables above 5 and require that count to be greater than lets say 10? I currently have the following code but it only calls the function once;

```
def min_qty_constraint(vars):
    count = 0
    for v in vars:
        if v.varValue > 5 :
            count += 1
    print count
    return -count

prob = pulp.LpProblem('problem',pulp.LpMaximize)
prob +=  min_qty_constraint(vars) <= 10
```

so for example if i had vars = [x1,x2,..,x20] where xi is a pulp.Lpvariable and x1,..,x10 = 6 then then 10 of these variables are greater than 5 thus fulfilling the contraitns that at least 10 variables have values greater than 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not linear. There is a way doing this with additional binary variables `y(i)`:

```
x(i) >= 5 y(i)
sum(i, y(i)) >= 10
```

(Note: I assumed `x(i)` are non-negative variables).